# magento 1.4.1.1 admin login problem

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm using Magento ver. 1.4.1.1.
I'm always able to login with the administrative account that was created during the installation.
I created new user and new role.After i assigned new role to new user.Also i made sure new user is active.

Now i try to login with new username and password the systems prompts that is an Invalid Username or Password.

How to solve this issue?

**Thanks and regards,**

*Logan*

Comment: have you cleared magento cache?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try the original administrator role.

If it logs in then there is a problem with the custom role.

The custom role I think in 1.4x requires global search to be checked. Otherwise there maybe a module that doesn't have permissions XML setup correctly in etc/config.xml